# Python class heritage

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have two classes `MyLib(object)` and `MyHash(MyLib)`.

```
class MyLib(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass        
    def inp (self):
        self.liblist = str(input()).split()        
    def librar(self):
        self.libdict = {item: self.liblist[index + 1] for index,
                        item in enumerate(self.liblist) if index % 2 == 0}
       
class MyHash(MyLib):
    def Hashing(self):
        self.hashkeys = list(MyLib.libdict.keys())
```

I'd like MyHash to get libdict from MyLib, and make some manipulations with it. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Because class `MyHash` extends `MyLib`, it also inherits all of `MyLib`'s fields. Thus, it will also have `self.libdict`. Of course, it has to be assigned first.

(Side note: Python makes no checks if the field is actually inherited, which means it even simpler: *the field exists iff it has been assigned*.)

Comment: I don't need libdict in MyHash, I want MyHash to take libdict from MyLib.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Are you talking about classes or instances? Is `libdict` supposed to be a static variable? The fact that `MyHash` inherits from `MyLib` implies that you *want* it there, so maybe you have not designed your classes properly? Perhaps you wanted to use *composition*?